# Force accessing to a class only through it's child

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I want to force access to a class only through its child class.

Imagine first class as:

```
//Parent class
public class A
{
    //blah blah
}
```

and second class as :

```
//Inherited from "A"
public class B : A
{
    //some more blah blah
}
```

and in third class:

```
public class C
{
    //To minimize the confusion for some reasons I don't want the  
    //rest of the programming team to be able to access  
    //the "A" class as if a class named "A" doesn't exist.
    //so the following variable should return
    //<type or namespace could not be found> error! or something similar
    private A the_A_Class;
    //Instead I want them to be able to access
    //the "B" class which is a child of "A" class.
    private B the_B_Class;
}
```

please let me know if I should clarify it more and
thanks in advance

Comment: This is a textbook [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual issue you're trying to solve? Why don't you want developers to know about the existence of the base class?

Comment: What's wrong with making all members of `A` protected or private?  Then `B` can expose some public methods or properties.  Maybe I'm missing something.  You can hide class `A` from IntelliSense with attributes if that's good enough.  `A` could be marked `internal` but that forces the same for derived classes.  If I had the same problem I would merely give `A` no public constructor(s), then hide it from IntelliSense, plus add XML comments on NOT using it.

Comment: @Zer0 That looks like a really good solution. As long as making `A` internal or private forces it to `B` as well, your solution of making constructors private looks promising, thanks a lot .

Comment: Simply make A abstract